# SQL Java java.lang.String incompatible with [Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: java, sql, list, arraylist

can someone help me with this Exception please and thank you :

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String incompatible with [Ljava.lang.Object;

```
String sql = "SELECT b.\"$adaptation\" FROM Address b where FK_AS_STRING('_businessPartner', '/root/Address', b.addressNumber) = ? AND b.bpGoldenId = ? AND b.isStandardAddress = ?";

String addressId = "TT";
String bpGoldenId = "pp";

        Query<Tuple> query = dataset.createQuery(sql);
        query.setParameter(0, addressId);
        query.setParameter(1, bpGoldenId); //Getting error here
        query.setParameter(2, true);
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `bpGoldenId` in your db

Comment: it's a String (for variables String String boolean). i tried also  (Object)bpGoldenId but same Exception

Comment: Can you debug your code to find exactly where is the error?

Comment: Yes i did it, you can check it in my 1st message (i get the error at this line ) :query.setParameter(1, bpGoldenId); //Getting error here

Comment: Change `query.setParameter(1, bpGoldenId)` to `query.setParameter(1, (String) bpGoldenId)`

Comment: thank you for your help, yes i tried this before and still have the same error